# How to gracefully unload a child AppDomain that has threads running

Tags: c#, concurrency, marshalling, appdomain

I have a service that loads a child AppDomain and then starts a thread running in it. It needs an AppDomain because it dynamically generates and loads some code and I need to be able to restart it without killing the whole service.

So there is a thread running in an event loop in the child AppDomain, it gets events passed to it through a MarshalByRefObject that sticks stuff in a concurrent queue. I want to stop and unload the child AppDomain and create a new one.

I can simply call Unload on the child AppDomain, but that will abort all the threads and throw a ThrearAbortException. How can I gracefully shut it down? If I set some static flag in the child AppDomain using the MarshalByRefObject then how will the main process be able to wait until its done unloading?

I have some example code that kind of shows how its setup and how I can call Unload to kill it, how could I modify this to allow graceful unloading and never have multiple child AppDomains?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestAppDomains
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Calls to methods magically get transfered to the appdomain it was created in because it derives from MarshalByRefObject
    /// </summary>
    class MarshalProxy : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public AppDomain GetProxyAppDomain()
        {
            return AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        }

        public void SayHello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MarshalProxy in AD: {0}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
        }

        public void RunLoop()
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("RunLoop {0} in {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You killed me! {0}", ex);
                Thread.Sleep(200); //just to make sure the unload is really blocking until its done unloading
                // if the sleep is set to 2000 then you will get a CannotUnloadAppDomainException, Error while unloading appdomain. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131015) thrown from the .Unload call
            }
        }

        static int creationCount = 1;
        public static MarshalProxy RunInNewthreadAndAppDomain()
        {
            // Create the AppDomain and MarshalByRefObject
            var appDomainSetup = new AppDomainSetup()
            {
                ApplicationName = "Child AD",
                ShadowCopyFiles = "false",
                ApplicationBase = Environment.CurrentDirectory,
            };

            var childAppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(
                "Child AD " + creationCount++,
                null,
                appDomainSetup,
                new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted));

            var proxy = (MarshalProxy)childAppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
                typeof(MarshalProxy).Assembly.FullName,
                typeof(MarshalProxy).FullName,
                false,
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance,
                null,
                new object[] { },
                null,
                null);

            Thread runnerThread = new Thread(proxy.RunLoop);
            runnerThread.Name = "MarshalProxy RunLoop";
            runnerThread.IsBackground = false;
            runnerThread.Start();

            return proxy;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am running in AD: {0}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);

            var proxy = MarshalProxy.RunInNewthreadAndAppDomain();
            proxy.SayHello();

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to kill and restart proxy");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Unloading");
                AppDomain.Unload(proxy.GetProxyAppDomain());
                Console.WriteLine("Done unloading");

                proxy = MarshalProxy.RunInNewthreadAndAppDomain();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stop the threads gracefully first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following

```
runnerThread.IsBackground = true;
```

And, yeah, there is no graceful unloading of AppDomain if you didn't stop the threads first.

Answer (score 2):

The situation is essentially the same as if the two AppDomains were separate processes, so you need to use some form of IPC. One option would be to pass an event handle into the child AppDomain when asking the loop to stop. The loop can signal the event before exiting. Wait for the event to give the loop some time to finish. If you time out, then you can do a rough unload.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize all child AppDomains. Send it to remote server. Turn that server off.